# Why nginx+php-fpm ignore memory_limit in php.ini?

Tags: php

Why nginx+php-fpm ignore memory_limit in php.ini? Timezone settings taken correctly, for example.
 But via pool settings (php_admin_value[memory_limit]) or nginx fastcgi_param all set. 
I do not understand this.
Where can I read about it?

My PHP version is 5.5

Comment: Most likely this is because you edit the wrong `php.ini` file. Modern distributions often have more than a single version for different usage of PHP. Check which file is read in by PHP: cann a `phpinfo();`, this gives you all the information about the current configuration.

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/fpm,  Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini. All right

Comment: And does that `phpinfo()` show the correct value you configured? If not, sure you have restarted the fpm server after changing the setting? (Note: not the http server, the fpm server)

Comment: yes. phpinfo() show the correct value

Comment: And a single php process takes more memory than what you configured? Never seen that...

Comment: Just to rule out that cause: the memory limit can be changed at runtime by a script. You don't do that either?

Comment: I know. Before i directly set memory_limit, i get error on phpinfo() calling —Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81920 bytes)

Comment: only on phpinfo() calling

Comment: Sorry, then this sounds like you have php processes still using the old configuration. I assume you did _not_ restart the fpm server.

Comment: I found a reason. Very-very wrong settings in current php.ini. I hear you says «hen this sounds like you have php processes still using the old configuration» and i got my [development configuration](https://gist.github.com/asakasinsky/4611263) and replace production ini to them. the problem is localized, there is no magic, and that's good. Thank you, arkascha! How i can close this  question?

Comment: Questions are not closed on SO. If you git answers you can accept one of them, but the questions here always stay visible. Great I could be of assistance.